# NSThread detachNewThreadSelector executing on main thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa

A small number of customers are getting hangs from my OS X app with the following hang log signature:

```
26 ??? [0x7fff93e87fc9]
26 ??? [0x7fff93e8372a]
  26 ??? [0x7fff93e83899]
    26 __NSThread__main__ + 1318 (Foundation) [0x7fff8be96dfb]
      26 -[AppController startClean] + 1319 (Housekeeper) [0x100007742]
        13 -[AppController trashMediaCache:] + 435 (Housekeeper) [0x100010e7a]
          13 +[MYFileManager trashFilesOfType:inFolder:] + 482 (Housekeeper) [0x100022e2a]
            13 +[MYFileManager trashFile:] + 22 (Housekeeper) [0x1000227f7]
              12 +[MYFileManager trashFile:shouldAuth:] + 226 (Housekeeper) [0x1000228de]
                12 -[NSWorkspace performFileOperation:source:destination:files:tag:] + 319 (AppKit) [0x7fff8aa72bbb]
                  12 -[NSWorkspace _fileOperation:source:destination:files:] + 917 (AppKit) [0x7fff8aa72f7e]
                    12 _FSOperateOnObjectSync + 482 (CarbonCore) [0x7fff87ab309c]
                      12 _NodeOperation + 488 (DesktopServicesPriv) [0x7fff90d6e38a]
                        4  TFSCopyOperation::DoMoveToTrash(TCountedPtr<TCFURLInfo> const&) + 330 (DesktopServicesPriv) [0x7fff90d7e28c]
                          4  TFSInfo::MoveAndRenameTo(TCountedPtr<TFSInfo> const&, TUString*, TCountedPtr<TFSInfo>&) const + 677 (DesktopServicesPriv) [0x7fff90da4ae7]
                            4  TCFURLInfo::RenameWithoutReplacing(char const*, char const*, bool) + 162 (DesktopServicesPriv) [0x7fff90d89620]
                              4  __rename + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib) [0x7fff861ba97a]
                                3  <Suppressed>
                        3  TFSCopyOperation::DoMoveToTrash(TCountedPtr<TCFURLInfo> const&) + 1033 (DesktopServicesPriv) [0x7fff90d7e54b]
                          3  THFSPlusPropertyStore::SetProperty(TUString const&, unsigned int, TPropertyReference const&) + 81 (DesktopServicesPriv) [0x7fff90d26bc1]
                            3  TDSMutex::Acquire() + 34 (DesktopServicesPriv) [0x7fff90ce5d00]
                              3  __psynch_mutexwait + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib) [0x7fff861ba746]
                                1  <Suppressed>
                        2  TFSCopyOperation::DoMoveToTrash(TCountedPtr<TCFURLInfo> const&) + 995 (DesktopServicesPriv) [0x7fff90d7e525]
                          2  THFSPlusPropertyStore::SetProperty(TUString const&, unsigned int, TPropertyReference const&) + 81 (DesktopServicesPriv) [0x7fff90d26bc1]
                            2  TDSMutex::Acquire() + 34 (DesktopServicesPriv) [0x7fff90ce5d00]
                              2  __psynch_mutexwait + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib) [0x7fff861ba746]
                                1  <Suppressed>
```

As you can see from the log, startClean is running on the main thread. But the confusing part is that there is only one call to startClean, as follows:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startClean) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

So the code should be executing on a separate thread, and indeed, that's the way it works on my system, but more than one customer has experienced this on OS X 10.9.5. There are a couple of calls to the main thread inside startClean, but these are only for updating the UI. The trashMediaCache call is executed by performSelector:withObject: but not performSelectorOnMainThread.

Has anyone seen this before? Is this an OS X bug or are there situations where the system will divert calls to the main thread by design? Or am I just misinterpreting the log?

P.S. I know I can use a dispatch call or operation queue and that might fix the issue but I'd still like to know the answer to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, your `startClean` method that runs in the background, triggers some code to run on the main thread, which causes a deadlock.
One possibility is that `startClean` uses *Core Data*. This is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344098/app-hangs-at-psynch-mutexwait).
Another possibility is a completion handler that is executed on the main thread. There are many, e.g. the `MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler`, where the docs state explicitly that they are always executed on the main thread.

Comment: I've been through my own code and I'm certain that nothing is going to the main thread, so it seems like it's most likely happening within Apple's code. I'll probably never get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 1):

`__NSThread__main__` is not the main thread. It is the internal entry point for an NSThread's execution.

Comment: Ah, I think you're right about that. I just got a hang report from a different app and the call stack started with `main` instead of `__NSThread__main__`.